# Applications launch on leftmost monitor in multi-monitor setup

Tags: gnome, nvidia, multiple-monitors

For some reason applications decide to launch on my leftmost monitor(which is my TV) instead of my primary(which is the monitor the the far right). It's not all applications that have this behavior but a good portion of them. VLC and BlueJ for instance are applications that won't launch on my preferred monitor, they always launch on my leftmost monitor. I won't matter if I close them on the monitor I wishes to open them on.
It also doesn't matter if I run Unity or Gnome Shell 3.10, the problem persist on both.
Here is my xrandr output to give you an idea on how my monitors are positioned. I run an Nvidia Gefore 670 with the proprietary and tested version of the drivers, 331.38.

```
xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 4480 x 1447, maximum 16384 x 16384
DVI-I-0 connected 1280x1024+1280+423 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 340mm x 270mm
   1280x1024      75.0*+   60.0  
   1024x768       75.0     70.1     60.0  
   800x600        75.0     72.2     60.3     56.2  
   640x480        75.0     72.8     59.9  
DVI-I-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-0 connected 1280x720+0+423 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 1434mm x 806mm
   1280x720       50.0*+   60.0     59.9  
   1920x1080      60.1     60.0     50.0  
   720x576        50.0     50.1  
   720x480        59.9     60.1  
   640x480        59.9  
DP-0 connected primary 1920x1080+2560+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 531mm x 299mm
   1920x1080      60.0*+   59.9     50.0     60.1     60.0     50.0  
   1680x1050      60.0  
   1600x1200      60.0  
   1440x900       75.0     59.9  
   1280x1024      75.0     60.0  
   1280x960       60.0  
   1280x800       59.8  
   1280x720       60.0     59.9     50.0  
   1152x864       75.0  
   1024x768       75.0     70.1     60.0  
   800x600        75.0     72.2     60.3     56.2  
   720x576        50.0  
   720x480        59.9  
   640x480        75.0     72.8     59.9  
DVI-D-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

Anyone who got an idea?

Edit. I've made a video to show the problem with the latest nvidia drivers 334.21.  Still the same problem. 
[Youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=my4kdwoPp2w&feature=youtu.be)